# Meaning of "knew from" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I'm trying to understand the usage of "knew from" in the following quote:

> (suddenly cleaning ladies knew from sun-dried tomatoes, suddenly hog farmers knew from creme brulee)

Source: [The Corrections](https://books.google.se/books?id=FodGfz5li5wC&lpg=PA198&ots=utDz7-I9-n&dq=suddenly%20cleaning%20ladies%20knew%20from%20sun-dried%20tomatoes&pg=PA198#v=onepage&q=suddenly%20cleaning%20ladies%20knew%20from%20sun-dried%20tomatoes&f=false)

To me (not a native English speaker), this seems ungrammatical. I understand the meaning of phrases like "know a from b", but I'm unable to parse this in any way that makes sense. Does "knew from" has some special meaning here?

Comment: [Here's a bit more context](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7NXzAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&dq=%22cleaning+ladies+knew+from%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Yvr1VM7-FM2y7QaHpIHoDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22cleaning%20ladies%20knew%20from%22&f=false). It seems clear to me the writer doesn't have a very firm grasp on "normal" written English (and there's every indication it's simply *badly-translated* material), so I think the cited usage is simply a ***mistake*** (typo or ignorance, take your pick).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in this case "knew from" doesn't mean deduced. It is a colloquial usage. I've mostly heard it used in the negative, in which a person says they "don't know from" sun dried tomatoes or crème brulee or whatever. When someone says it like that, they're usually portraying themselves as a simple down-to-earth person confronted with some outlandish new-fangled absurdity. Literally it means you don't know *about* this that or the other thing.
As noted above, it derives from a Yiddish translation.
In your passage, the writer was saying something about unsophisticated folk suddenly having the means of being savvy about fancy-shmancy (another Yiddishism, I believe) high-dollar noshes (to complete the Yiddish trifecta).

Comment: It **is** a Negative Polarity Item, and therefore its use here is a matter of adding strangeness to the phenomenon -- lower-class people suddenly are familiar with the food of the upper class. It's a Yiddish idiom passed into New York English.

Answer (score -1):

Well I think grammatically the sentence seems correct, even though the style is a tad informal. I haven't seen this usage a lot in writing, but reading a couple of examples you've used, didn't strike me oddly. "Knew from" could easily be a synonym for deduce. So your example sentences could also be used as "suddenly cleaning ladies deduced from sun-dried tomatoes that..." Please let me know if you're looking for a different answer.

Comment: I don't think that works, the sentence does not continue with anything like your suggestion (see full context in link).

Comment: Well I regret to say that was the only usage I'm aware of. I think another user by the name Sarah has given a more compelling answer to your question. Hopefully it'd be satisfying to you.